# Turn off FireFox driver refresh POST warning

Tags: firefox, selenium, geb

I have inherited some GEB tests that are testing logging into a site (and various error cases/validation warnings).

The test runs through some validation failures and then it attempts to re-navigate to the same page (just to refresh the page/dom) and attempts a valid login. Using GEB's to() method, it detects that you are attempting to navigate to the page you are on, it just calls refresh - the problem here is that attempts to refresh the last POST request, and the driver displays the

"**To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier**"

message - as the test is not expecting this popup, it hangs and the tests timeout.

Is there a way to turn off these warnings in Firefox webdriver? or to auto-ignore/accept them via Selenium or GEB?

GEB Version: 0.9.2, 
Selenium Version: 2.39.0

(Also tried with minor version above: 0.9.3 & 2.40.0)

Caveats:

- I know about the POST/Re-direct/GET pattern - but am not at liberty    to change the application code in this case
- The warning message only    causes an issue intermittently (maybe 1 in 5 times) - I have put this down to speed/race conditions whereby the test completes the next actions before the message appears - I know a possible solution is to update tests to wait for message to appear and then accept, but my question is, is there a global setting that can just avoid these being triggered/displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you issue properly this might help. In Groovy you can modify a class on the fly.

We use Spock with Geb and I placed this in a Super class which all Spock Spec inherit from. Eg: QSpec extends GebSpec.

It is the original method slightly modified with the original code commented out so you know what has been changed. I use this technique in several required places to alter Geb behaviour.

```
static {

    Browser.metaClass.go = { Map params, String url ->
        def newUrl = calculateUri(url, params)
        //          if (driver.currentUrl == newUrl) {
        //              driver.navigate().refresh()
        //          } else {
        //              driver.get(newUrl)
        //          }
        driver.get(newUrl)
        if (!page) {
            page(Page)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :) this is actually pretty close to a solution I considered - wasn't sure if overriding the go() method might have problems later on if we wanted to keep upgrading GEB versions - although can't see there being much change there.

Comment: If it helps I changed this and had no issues. There was another method I changed for PageChangeListening aswell that might help. I'll check it at work if you need.

Answer (score 3):

That `refresh()` is there to work around an issue with IE driver which ignores calls to `driver.get()` with the same url as the current one.

Instead of monkey patching Browser class (which might bite you somewhere down the line or might not) I would change the url of your login page class. You might for example add an insignificant query string - I think that simply a `?` at the end should suffice. The `driver.currentUrl == newUrl` condition will evaluate to false and you will not see that popup anymore.

Comment: Nice elegant solution. It's also good to know that the refresh was in there for IE. It's strange though, the reason I changed this was because of IE and how it behaved with Stepwise tests?